# Should "office mate" be one word or two?

Tags: nouns

Should "office mate" be one word, in the same vein as "roommate"? I haven't been able to find any reference that addresses this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a noun-noun compound, and they vary in spelling **a lot**. *Officemate, office-mate, office mate, roommate, bed mate, mincemeat, mince-meat, minced meat*, etc.

There is no official spelling for such compounds, which are formed *ad libitum* in spoken English. Whatever looks good to you will work; English readers are mostly cooperative.

If anyone objects, you can write it off as being simply [peevage](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?cat=62).

Comment: I'm not sure what "official spelling" means in the context of changing usage, but it may be worth pointing out that my 1983 copy of Chambers has **work-mate**, whereas the 2011 edition has **workmate**. Personally, I'd either use *workmate* or *colleague* anyway. *Office mate* sounds a bit clunky to me, however it's spelt.

Answer (score 2):

Merriam-Webster lists *[roommate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/roommate)* as a word, but neither *officemate* nor *office mate* is listed. (My spell-checker flags *officemate* as wrong.)

As the following [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=office%20mate,officemate&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows, *office mate* outstrips *officemate* in usage. (Many of the occurrences of *officemate* are accounted for by [software products](http://www.officemate.net/) of that name.)

[image: office mate vs officemate]

Comment: Remember, Google Ngram Viewer is case-sensitive so OfficeMate is excluded from your chart.

Comment: @Hugo But when I look up the examples it gives from the corpus, I see OfficeMATE, Officemate, and, OfficeMate, etc., which is what led me to conclude that many of the contributions were coming from those sorts of sources.

Comment: Yes, care is needed: when you click the link below the case-sensitive Ngram, it takes you to case-insensitive Google Books results.

Answer (score 2):

The OED has an entry called "office-man" that does not appear to be hyphenated in its later uses.

ˈoffice-man
†1.1 An officer; an official. Sc. Obs. 
1908 J. M. Sullivan Criminal Slang 17 Office man, headquarters detective.    1921 Daily Colonist (Victoria, B.C.) 12 Oct. 16/2 (Advt.), Wanted—position as office man, watchman, warehouse, or place of trust.    1949 Partridge Dict. Underworld 479/1 Office man, a headquarters detective.

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling that there is a tendency to gradually drop hyphens and move towards a hyphenfree (hyphen-free/ hyphen free) English.

1. [The current trend is toward closed compounds...](http://www.stc-carolina.org/newsletter/tiki-index.php?page=The%20Humble%20Hyphen)
2. In 2007, (the National Geographic) [announced](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aYmOHI-2YOwUJ%3ablogs.ngm.com/rogers_rules/2007/10/index.html%20%22Are%20Hyphens%20Going%20Extinct?%22%20Oct%2012,2007) cutbacks on hyphen use in
   compounds...
3. (The) new sixth edition of the [Shorter Oxford
   English Dictionary](http://www.askoxford.com/worldofwords/wordfrom/soed6/?view=uk), ... has managed to eliminate some 16,000
   hyphens out of 600,000 entries. (quoted from the above.)

Answer (score 1):

I would make a decision applying a similar perspective as with the word **roommate**. By separating the words, *office* and *mate*, it seems to emphasize the ***mate*** part, which is not the intent in an office context, just like it isn't in a co-habitation context e.g. *room **mate***.

Secondary consideration: Corporate usage. There are numerous examples of major businesses named **officemate**, a single word. See **[OfficeMate](http://www.officemate.net/officemate_overview.aspx)**:

> the world's major provider of practice management software for eyecare
>   practices

as well as **[Officemate International Corporation](http://www.officemate.com/2_Products/AllProducts.html)** (OIC):

> the leading manufacturer of office essentials...sold at thousands of
>   office product suppliers all over the world.

*This is rather subjective, but I noticed that a prior answer already provided the full ngram treatment.

Comment: I will mention that both Stack Exchange AND the WordPress spellchecker red line *officemate*, with *office mate* the preferred spelling!

Comment: Most likely because it thinks that you missed hitting the space bar, so it tries to separate the words.

Comment: @Mahnax It *thinks*? Oh if only it could.

Answer (score 1):

Listen to how the word is pronounced.  If you hear separate stress on "OFF-ice" and "MATE", then you should certainly treat it as two words.

If you hear only one stress ("OFF-ice-mate"), and if you hear it very often, then you can try writing it as "office-mate".  If nobody corrects you then, congratulations, you have played a part in the formation of a new English word.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using it in a corporate or business context then make it one word: officemate. In creative writing use it as you like. Either way, be consistent.